# Get correlation between a subset of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, covariance

So, I am familiar with some more advanced Pandas indexing and with using `.apply()` on columns/rows of data, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to get a variance-covariance matrix for some columns manually without reverting to `.corr()`.

Whenever I try the following to slice the columns I want (all rows, and all columns after "APPL R"),

```
a = np.cov(data1.loc[:,'AAPL R':])
```

I get an answer like

```
array([[  7.27823733e-04,   2.26078140e-04,   1.99410574e-04, ...,
          9.57801851e-05,  -2.76751908e-04,   5.71509542e-05],
       [  2.26078140e-04,   1.26173616e-04,   2.17306383e-04, ...,
          3.30070375e-05,  -2.47989495e-05,   1.16819595e-05],
       [  1.99410574e-04,   2.17306383e-04,   1.92984210e-03, ...,
         -2.27400788e-04,  -4.46589343e-05,  -5.90865613e-05],
       ..., 
       [  9.57801851e-05,   3.30070375e-05,  -2.27400788e-04, ...,
```

How could I manually get a simple output like this in Pandas?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on not using `DataFrame.corr()`:

- You aren't sending the correct lists to the `numpy` function. You want each column as its own list, so you should be using the **transpose** of the DataFrame.
- You want the correlation matrix, not the covariance matrix, so you should be using `np.corrcoef()`. (If you really want the covariance matrix, then fine use `np.cov()`)

Here's a `df` I had in memory from another question.

```
             open   high    low  close  volume
date                                          
2017-11-01  44.66  44.75  42.19  42.93    3500
2017-11-03  44.66  44.75  42.19  42.93    3500
2017-11-06  43.15  43.75  40.60  41.02    9200
2017-11-07  43.15  43.75  40.60  41.02    9200
2017-11-08  43.15  43.75  40.60  41.02    9200
2017-11-09  43.15  43.75  40.60  41.02    9200
2017-11-10  43.15  43.75  40.60  41.02    9200
2017-11-13  41.60  43.21  40.03  42.36    3575
2017-11-14  41.60  43.21  40.03  42.36    3575
...

df.corr()
#            open      high       low     close    volume
#open    1.000000  0.891708  0.957078  0.351604  0.320314
#high    0.891708  1.000000  0.878307  0.610183  0.311939
#low     0.957078  0.878307  1.000000  0.559366  0.146151
#close   0.351604  0.610183  0.559366  1.000000 -0.132609
#volume  0.320314  0.311939  0.146151 -0.132609  1.000000

np.corrcoef(df.loc[:,'open':].values.T)
#array([[ 1.        ,  0.89170836,  0.95707833,  0.35160354,  0.32031362],
#       [ 0.89170836,  1.        ,  0.87830748,  0.61018322,  0.31193906],
#       [ 0.95707833,  0.87830748,  1.        ,  0.55936625,  0.14615072],
#       [ 0.35160354,  0.61018322,  0.55936625,  1.        , -0.13260909],
#       [ 0.32031362,  0.31193906,  0.14615072, -0.13260909,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: So creating the transpose is the key >.< . I can't believe I didn't realize that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using `corr` from `pandas`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'V1':[1,2,3],'V2':[3,2,1],'V3':[3,4,9]})
df.corr()
Out[431]: 
          V1        V2        V3
V1  1.000000 -1.000000  0.933257
V2 -1.000000  1.000000 -0.933257
V3  0.933257 -0.933257  1.000000
```